# How to get json of products/storeConfig by making a request with an url?

Tags: api, json

I'd like to setup Magento so that if I make a request with an URL such as: 
http://mymagento.com/api/storeconfig (actual url format not important)

would return json with the data requested. How can I achieve this? Here's how I'm retrieving the data:

```
public function getStoreSettings()
{
    //this successfully retrieves the value of my custom settings property
    $my_property= Mage::getStoreConfig('my_module/my_settings/my_property', 'default');

    $data = array('my_property'=>$my_property);
    $json = Mage::helper('core')->jsonEncode($data);

    //return json here
}
```

Where would the right place to add this code? How can I map an URL to call this function and return the response as json? I appreciate if anyone could point me in the right direction!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After lots of playing around with Magento, trying to figure out all the magic going on, I found a solution to my problem, and am adding a solution for those who may come across the same task.

1 - Go to your app/etc/modules/YourPackage_YourModule.xml
This is what I have:

```
<config>
  <modules>
    <YourPackage_YourModule>
      <active>true</active>
      <codePool>community</codePool>
    </YourPackage_YourModule>
  </modules>

  <frontend>
        <routers>
            <yourmodule>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module>YourPackage_YourModule</module>
                    <frontName>yourmodule</frontName>
                </args>
            </yourmodule>
        </routers>
    </frontend>
</config>
```

this will create a route for http://yourmagento.com/yourmodule/yourcontroller/youraction

2- Go to app/code/community/YourPackage/YourModule/controllers/
Create your YourController.php. This is mine:

```
<?php

class YourPackage_YourModule_YourController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action
{

    public function indexAction()
    { 
        $response = array('my_key'=> 'my_value');

        $this->getResponse()->clearHeaders()->setHeader('Content-type','application/json',true);
        $this->getResponse()->setBody(json_encode($response));
    }
}

?>
```

There's a lot of magic going on with the naming conventions, for a more in-depth walk-through, check out [Magento for Developers: Part 3 - Magento Controller Dispatch](http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/magento-for-dev-part-3-magento-controller-dispatch)